# visual studio 2010 to follow strict OOP rules

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oop

I am trying to learn coding that follow strict OOP concepts and best practices while writing a program.
Is there any feature/option in VS2010 that can allow only best programing practice else give error??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best practices are soooo broad. What someone might consider a 'best practice' someone else might consider not relevant. Similarly best practice in one context might be a bad idea in another.

Comment: Here is a start: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/  Also, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=studio+best+practices+%5Bvisual-studio%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much it helps but there is something you can do.

In Solution Explorer right click to project and select properties, there will be a tab named "Compile". There you can edit warning and errors options.

There is "Option Strict" property, so make sure you change it to "ON". And below that there is a list you can specify warning configurations. Change any of them "warning" or "error"

I hope this will help you. Good luck with your learning.